# How to prove that every number of the form $245\cdot 22..11-239$ is congruent to $10^m \mod 41$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider Numbers:

\begin{align}
245&\cdot 211-239\\
245&\cdot 2211-239\\
245&\cdot 22211-239\\
245&\cdot 222211-239{}{}{}\\
245&\cdot 2222\ldots11-239
\end{align}
I am stuck, how to prove that every number of this form is congruent to $10^m \bmod 41$ for some $m$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin try it

Comment: __Hint:__ Express $ 11\ldots 11 = (10^m - 1 ) / 9$. Then you can proceed per the usual methods (whether it's FLT or induction that you're used to for such problems)).

Comment: $10^5 \equiv 1 \mod 41$ might help

Comment: Let $a_n$ denote the $n^\text{th}$ term, then the question asked us to prove that $a_{n+1} - 10^n $ is divisible by 41. Taking the finite difference, $a_{n+1} - a_n = 49 \cdot 10^{n+3} $. So what's left to do is to prove that $49 \cdot 10^{n+3} - 10^{n} + 10^{n-1} $ is divisible by 41. Can you finish it off from here?

Comment: All good, but why answer the question in the comments? Put these down as answers is my take!

Comment: Note that $245\equiv -1 \bmod 41$ so the factor of $245$ in each example can be replaced by a minus sign. Each example becomes a negative number that is a string of $2$s and ends in $450$

Comment: $$245\cdot 22211-239=5441456\equiv 18 \bmod 41$$

Comment: Given the attention this question has received, it is disappointing that it is closed. I have a more concise answer that I cannot post other than as a comment: $245\cdot 22\dots 11-239=245(2000\frac{10^m-1}{9}+211)-239$. Using the congruences: $245\equiv -1,\ 2000\equiv -9,\ 451\equiv 0 \bmod 41$ we get $(-1)(-9)\frac{10^m-1}{9}+(-1)(211)-239 \equiv 10^m-1-211-239=10^m-451\equiv 10^m \bmod 41$ QED for all $m\ge 0$

Comment: @keith Backman i suspect that this question has something to do with ec primes. By the way 451 is one of the esponents leading to an ec prime.

Answer (score 3):

Since $1..1$ with $n$ ones is equal to $\frac{10^n-1}{9}$, we can write the general term of the sequence as
$$
a_n = 245 \cdot \Big(200 \cdot \frac{10^n-1}{9} + 11\Big) - 239.
$$
Looking modulo 41 we have $245 \equiv -1$, $200 \equiv -5$, $-239 \equiv 7$ and $9^{-1} \equiv -9$ (since $9 \times (-9) = -81 \equiv 1$). We can write
\begin{align*}
a_n
&\equiv (-1) \cdot 9^{-1} (-5) (10^{n}- 1) - 11 + 7 \\
&\equiv 9 \cdot  (-5 \cdot 10^{n} + 5) -4 \\
&\equiv -45 \cdot 10^{n} + 45 - 4 \\
&\equiv -4 \cdot 10^n \\
&\equiv -40 \cdot 10^{n-1}\\
&\equiv 10^{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1). There's typo in last third line from the last: $\equiv -4 \cdot 10^n \equiv -40 \cdot 10^{n-1} \equiv 10^{n-1}$.

Comment: Actually, notice that I put a $\pm$ sign: $-4 \cdot 10^n \pm 10^{n-1}$, meaning to sum and subtract the same quantity. But I guess it is a little confusing. Better to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n = 245\cdot 2222\cdots11-239$ with $n$ $2$'s. Then $a_n \equiv 10^{n-1}$. (All congruences are mod $41$.)

Indeed, $a_{n+1}-a_n = 245 \cdot (2 \cdot 10^{n+2}) \equiv 9 \cdot 10^{n-1} $.

Now let $b_n = 10^{n-1}$. Then $b_{n+1}-b_n \equiv 9 \cdot 10^{n-1} \equiv a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Since $a_1 \equiv 1 \equiv b_1 \bmod 41$, we have $a_n \equiv b_n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Below I thought it through and  that is why I can conclude that:

$10^4 \equiv -4 \pmod {41}$. $245\equiv -1\pmod {41}$. $239 \equiv -7 \pmod {41}$.  And $9^{-1}\equiv -9$.  That is if $k=9k'$ is divisible by $9$ then $(-9)k =(-9)\cdot 9k'= -81k'\equiv k'$.

So:

$245\cdot\underbrace{22222....2}_m11 -239\equiv$

$245\cdot 200\cdot\frac {10^m-1}9 + 245\cdot 11 - 239\equiv$

$-1\cdot (-9)\cdot 200\cdot(10^m - 1)-11 + 7\equiv$

$9\cdot (-5)(10^m-1)-4\equiv$

$-4(10^m-1) - 4\equiv -4(10^m) + 4 - 4 \equiv -4(10^m) \equiv 10^4\cdot 10^m \equiv 10^{m+4}\pmod {41}$

==== Now here is how a figured that out: ====

Let's work backwards. $10^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod {41}$.

$10^2 \equiv 18\pmod {41}$

$10^3 \equiv 180\equiv 16 \pmod {41}$

$10^4 \equiv 160 \equiv 37\equiv -4 \pmod {41}$

$10^5 \equiv -40 \equiv 1 \pmod {41}$.  So there are only $5$ powers of $10$ in $\mod 41$. (because $10^{5k + j} \equiv (10^5)^k\cdot 10^j \equiv 1\cdot 10^j\pmod {41}$.

Now bear with me:

As there are only $5$ possible values of $10^m$ there are only $5$ values of $10^m -1 = \underbrace{999...9}_m$ and of $\frac {10^m-1}9 =\underbrace{1111...1}_m$ and of $245\cdot 200\cdot{10^m-1}9 + 245\cdot 11 - 239=245\cdot\underbrace{22222....2}_m11 -239$.

(Note: $9$ is invertible in $\mod 41$ so dividing by $9$ doesn't add any extraneous values.)

So lets just calculate them all.

It helps to realize $245\equiv -1 \pmod{41}$ and that $9^{-1}\equiv -9$ as $9\cdot (-9)\equiv -81 \equiv 1 \pmod {41}$ and $239 \equiv -7$.

$245\cdot\underbrace{22222....2}_m11 -239\equiv$

$245\cdot 200\cdot\frac {10^m-1}9 + 245\cdot 11 - 239\equiv$

$-1\cdot (-9)\cdot 200\cdot(10^m - 1)-11 + 7\equiv$

$9\cdot (-5)(10^m-1)-4\equiv$

$-4(10^m-1) - 4\equiv -4(10^m) + 4 - 4 \equiv -4(10^m) \equiv 10^4\cdot 10^m \equiv 10^{m+4}\pmod {41}$

oh.... cool.  We didn't have to calculate any of them.